# Custom optimiser implementation in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use a custom optimiser to train a NN in Keras. The original algorithm has been developed to train CNNs and is based on using different adaptive learning rates for every weight of the network. The algorithm is called WAME (weight-wise adaptive learning rates with moving average estimator).
The optimiser has been developed by a former University of London student and can be found in [this](https://github.com/rlh1994/cw_wame_optimiser_cnn/blob/master/ml_cw.py) GitHub repo (lines 54 to 153).

As you can see in the code, it is built as a subclass of the optimizer_v2 superclass available in TensorFlow. This class is called WAMEprop.

What I am trying to do is simply:

- pasting the code that defines the class into my Google Colab notebook
- using the new optimizer as follows:

```
#building the model
wame_model = models.Sequential()
wame_model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)))
wame_model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
wame_model.add(layers.Dense(1))

#compiling the model using WAMEprop as optimizer
wame_model.compile(optimizer=WAMEprop(name='wame'), loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

#fitting the model
history = wame_model.fit(train_features, train_targets,
                    validation_data=(test_features, test_targets),
                    epochs=50, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a13c54fc61f2> in <module>()
      5 wame_model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
      6 wame_model.add(layers.Dense(1))
----> 7 wame_model.compile(optimizer=WAMEprop(name='wame'), loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
      8 
      9 history = wame_model.fit(white_train_features_df_s.to_numpy(), white_train_targets.to_numpy(),

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get(identifier)
    131   else:
    132     raise ValueError(
--> 133         'Could not interpret optimizer identifier: {}'.format(identifier))

ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <__main__.WAMEprop object at 0x7fd4bc1d01d0>
```

Since I am new to Keras and I, unfortunately, don't know Tensorflow, I am not sure what exactly it is not able to find.
Did I get some import wrong?
Did I use the keras compile() method in the wrong way?
Also, if I don't pass the parameter name='wame' to the WAMEprop() call, I get an error message saying that the positional argument 'name' is required. Strangely enough, there is no parameter 'name' in the class constructor. Does this depend on the interaction with the superclass?

Thank you very much a lot in advance for any help you could offer!

Cheers!

UPDATE:
the error message refers to a method `get()` that takes as input `identifier` in the optimizers.py file that must have been installed with TensorFlow. Now, this function is expecting to get a string (I guess fr the readily available optimizers), a configuration dictionary, an `optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2` object or a `tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer` object.

I think the object I am passing as an optimizer is no one of these.
If I run:

```
my_optimizer = WAMEprop(name='wame')
print(type(my_optimizer))
```

I get `<class '__main__.WAMEprop'>`.

So, I suspect the object I am dealing with is something different from what Keras is expecting.

UPDATE2: it runs on my laptop, I have tensorflow installed within an Anaconda environment. Now, I am convinced there is some installation or import problem in Google Colab

Comment: Can you try this implementation? https://github.com/justinbt1/WAME-Optimiser

Comment: @M.Innat, Thanks for replying. I did try that implementation and it was working, but the problem was that it was terribly unstable.
Sometimes I would obtain nicely small and decreasing values for the mean absolute error (which I used as validation). Some other times, I would get "exploding" values, like 100, 5000, or so (when the actual output values should range from 0 to 10). Would you have any suggestions about this?
Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the optimizer implementation you use is made using tf.keras, while you are using the keras library, these are not the same libraries and are incompatible to each other. You need to use oly one of these libs.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy thanks a lot! Should I use tf.keras.something when building the network and compiling it? For example tf.keras.layers?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use this implementation, you should use tf.keras for everything.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I did use the following imports: `import tensorflow as tf`,
`from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`,
`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense`. I edited the model definition accordingly (i.e., removing layer. before Dense, etc), yet it does not work. Would you please have any other suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I needed to uninstall tensorflow 2.6.0 from Google Colab and install tensorflow 2.0.0 instead.